# I want to make a slider with interchanged instead of moving with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

In this slider, I want to make the images interchanged instead of moving, I mean like the first image fades out from its place and the second one fade in replacing the first one - at the place of the first image -, and the second one fades out from its place and the third one fades in replacing the second one - at the place of the second image -

```
<div class="side-imgs">
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/Egypt_header_sm.jpg)" > </div>
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/28273351-chilling-out-sitting-rim-cliff-in-the-mountain.jpg)"> </div>
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/180933-1-Blue_Lagoon,_Dahab,_Egypt.jpg)"> </div>
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/cairo2013-700x.jpg)"> </div>
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/cairo_giza_gizeh_egypt_pyramid_camels_camel_donkey-327500.jpg_d_str7yz.jpg)" ></div> 
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/egypt-tourism-authority-launches-first-new-global-marketing-campaign-in-more-than-four-years-seeking-to-double-number-of-visitors-by-2020.jpg)" > </div>
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/Egypt_header_sm.jpg)" > </div>
                      <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/luxorfuntours.png)" > </div>
                      <div class="eac-img"  style="background-image: url(images/unnamed.jpg)"> </div>
                        <div class="eac-img" style="background-image: url(images/Egypt_header_sm.jpg)" > </div>     
                      <div class="eac-img"  style="background-image: url(images/28273351-chilling-out-sitting-rim-cliff-in-the-mountain.jpg)" > </div>

                  </div>
```

I tried using this code but it's not working

```
 var i;
    var theimg = $('.side-imgs .eac-img'); 

        for (i = 0; i < theimg.length; i++) {

           theimg.eq(i).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).delay(3000);
        }
```

I also tried this one but it's not working well too

```
(function autoSlider() { 

        $('.side-imgs .eac-img').each(function () {
                        $(this).delay(4000).fadeOut(100).next().fadeIn(200);

        });
                autoSlider();  


    }());
```

I converted the divs into images to change the src

```
<div class="side-imgs">
                      <div class="side-overlay"></div>
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/Egypt_header_sm.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/28273351-chilling-out-sitting-rim-cliff-in-the-mountain.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/180933-1-Blue_Lagoon,_Dahab,_Egypt.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/cairo2013-700x.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/cairo_giza_gizeh_egypt_pyramid_camels_camel_donkey-327500.jpg_d_str7yz.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/egypt-tourism-authority-launches-first-new-global-marketing-campaign-in-more-than-four-years-seeking-to-double-number-of-visitors-by-2020.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/Egypt_header_sm.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/28273351-chilling-out-sitting-rim-cliff-in-the-mountain.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/180933-1-Blue_Lagoon,_Dahab,_Egypt.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/cairo2013-700x.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img " src="images/cairo_giza_gizeh_egypt_pyramid_camels_camel_donkey-327500.jpg_d_str7yz.jpg)" >
                      <img class="eac-img" src="images/egypt-tourism-authority-launches-first-new-global-marketing-campaign-in-more-than-four-years-seeking-to-double-number-of-visitors-by-2020.jpg" >
                      <img class="eac-img" src="images/luxorfuntours.png" >




                  </div>
```

and I used this JS code but still not working

```
function slidingImages()
{
    images = ['images/Egypt_header_sm.jpg', 'images/28273351-chilling-out-sitting-rim-cliff-in-the-mountain.jpg','images/180933-1-Blue_Lagoon,_Dahab,_Egypt.jpg','images/cairo2013-700x.jpg','images/cairo_giza_gizeh_egypt_pyramid_camels_camel_donkey-327500.jpg_d_str7yz.jpg','images/egypt-tourism-authority-launches-first-new-global-marketing-campaign-in-more-than-four-years-seeking-to-double-number-of-visitors-by-2020.jpg'];

   var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
   document.querySelectorAll('.side-imgs .eac-img').src= random;

    setTimeout(slidingImages, 2000);
}


slidingImages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your parent class is `"show-img"` and in the Javascript code you showed the parent class is `"side-imgs"`, consider giving a look at your code before seeking help, you can learn more by doing that.

This thread was covered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498656/how-to-create-fade-in-out-transitions-between-elements-of-image-array-in-vanilla)

But I made an example of how you can achieve that, find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/edonrexhepi/t9dph1gm/

The above code will iterate in all Nodes with the className of `images--each` and for each will change the index of the 'currentSlide' and 'prevSlide' variables, will add the 'visible' className to the index is going to, and will remove it from the one leaving.

---

UPDATE: Based on the comment below

Please check this fork: 
https://jsfiddle.net/edonrexhepi/9vmpjh67/

I've mixed jQuery and Vanilla, please let me know if this is what you wanted to do, I'll cleanup the code a bit more.

BTW, why don't you use smth like Swiper or Flickity?

Comment: your code is working well if it's one image slider, I want it 3 images shown but randomly changing, "the slider is 3 images shown that I want them to interchange with all the images of the slider", I converted the divs into images and used another code but still not working "I'll edit the question and put the code"

Comment: @IbrahimYousry please check the update on the Reply; Is this something you're seeking?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just manipulate that through inserting/removing styles:

```
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.eac-img');
currentindex = 0;
const nextImg = () => {

  img[currentIndex].classList.remove('active');
  currentIndex++;

  if (currentIndex === imageSlide.length) {
      currentIndex = 0;
  }

  imageSlide[currentIndex].classList.add('active');

}
```

Just make sure that you make the class 'active' {display: block} and the others {disbplay: none}. This way, when 'active' is removed, the image disapears, and the next image will appear, because it will have the class 'active';